# create table for user/visitors in drupal website

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

i tried creating a table for user in which he can update certain (through text box )things and those things are shown on website(drupal) just after submitting .i used webform,flexiform but failed.

Comment: What do you want the users to update and what do you want to display? If you provide details, you can get a solution.

Comment: suppose there are 4column in table with text field in each whatever they enter(mostly text) ,after submitting it should be updated on same page above/below.

Comment: Are you using Drupal 7.x? You can add fields to user's account and save them to db. Using views, you can then retrieve those values per user basis.

Comment: yes i m using drupal 7.x. and i want data to be showed regardless the user (who so ever it is the data should be shown on site).is it possible.